# Question about the quantity theory of money

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, money-supply, quantity-theory-of-money

M = Money supply

V = Velocity = Number of times the average bill changes hands in a time period.

P = Price

Y = Output

T = Transactions

Quantity equation

M * V = P * Y,

M * V = P * T

1. Why do we have MV on one side, and not M only? Doesn't V already count for M, since V already counts, or at least uses, the quantity of available money in the economy?
2. If T=Y, does the quantity theory of money assume that all what is produced is purchased? Why?

Comment: In your equation, what is T? And why the Economic Growth tag?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_theory_of_money#:~:text=In%20monetary%20economics%2C%20the%20quantity,in%20circulation%2C%20or%20money%20supply.)  article about the quantity theory of money defines and explains it all in my opinion.

Comment: T = Transactions